# Python button auto triggering when tkinter open window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have python tkinter code that uses a button to process data, but when I open the window the values are instantly sent without pressing the button. is there a way to do this similarly.

```py
apply_button = Button(
    settings_window,
    text="Apply",
    command=process(
        value1.get(),
        value2.get(),
        value3.get(),
        value4.get(),
    ),
)

apply_button.pack()
```

Comment: In order for us to help you, for one, you're going to need to let us know what GUI toolkit you're even using. Additionally, a more thorough, testable example would probably help too.

Comment: @ken i am using tkinter

Comment: I suggested some edits to clarify that. Unfortunately I don't know much about tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

It seams to be Tkinter. You can use the `command=lambda:` function when you want to pass arguments to a callback function.

Code:

```
apply_button = Button(settings_window, text="Apply", command=lambda: process(value1.get(), value2.get(), value3.get(), value4.get()))
apply_button.pack()
```

Explanation of the lambda function:
http://zetcode.com/python/lambda/#:~:text=Python%20lambda%20with%20Tkinter,functions%20for%20the%20command%20parameter.&text=We%20have%20three%20buttons%20that,data%20to%20the%20callback%20function.